# What is the issue with not overriding templates in symfony2.6 and FOSUserBundle 1.3

Tags: symfony, templates, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the base layout of FOSUserBundle using the 'simple' option of making a cloned path as `.app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` , but symfony2.6 continues to render the template from inside the vendor directory.

My composer requires:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3"
},
```

I've checked the following common issues:

- filesystem case sensitivity - looks OK
- having the correct path - seems OK
- clearing the cache: both manually and from the app/console - no problem here

Other information:
 - runs on a vagrant instance with ubuntu-trusty-64
 - the synced folder is through NFS

Any ideas in what I should look or do next ?

Comment: By any chance any of your bundles is a child of FOSUserBundle?

Comment: @ggioffreda No, I tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had mostly nothing to do with Symfony2 or FOSUserBundle, but with the way PHP caches the file stats.

To locate the right template to load, standard Symfony2 uses `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->locateResource` , by first checking if an override exists in the `.app\Resources` directory and if the `$first` parameter is set to true it returns from inside the foreach loop.

In my configuration, PHP decided to keep using the filecache and answer no to file_exists even if the file was there.

To go around / fix this problem my `AppKernel.php` overrides the `locateResource` of the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` class:

```
<?php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // .. other methods here

    public function locateResource($name, $dir = null, $first = true)
    {
        clearstatcache(true);
        return parent::locateResource($name, $dir, $first);
    }
}
```

Not pretty, but it works.