# FOSUserBundle not overriding twig template in specific cases

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am using `FOSUserBundle` in some Symfony2 Projects.

To override the login page, I normally create a `Twig` file like this:  `/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/security/login.html.twig`.

In the past projects I created, this worked normally and did override the login page.

Recently, I have been working on a new Symfony project with a teammate. Overriding the login page **worked** in my environment but **NOT** in his environment. We tried uploading the project to a test server where it also **didn't** override the login page (It used to override it for other projects we tested).

We are using Symfony 2.7 with Linux Distros for all the environments. In my case, I use Ubuntu Server. My teammate runs Ubuntu Mate and the test server runs Ubuntu.

We checked folder permissions and ownerships and everything is ok.

Everything in the project works **except** this little twig override for the FOSUserBundle login page.

We already tried php `clear:cache` and manually deleting the cache folder.

We also tried this solution: [What is the issue with not overriding templates in symfony2.6 and FOSUserBundle 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405308/what-is-the-issue-with-not-overriding-templates-in-symfony2-6-and-fosuserbundle), where the answer suggests that the problem is the way PHP caches the file stats. This also didnt' work.

Any suggestions or maybe some PHP configs that we could try?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a problem with a case sensitivity.

Change it to `/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig` (lower case *s* -> upper case *S*). And then check by `ls -l` (also check your version control if relevant).

Comment: Wow! We were so worried that it could be some misconfiguration, but this actually worked.
Crazy thing: Case sensitivity was "ignored" on my Ubuntu Server environment, guess it is because I am running it on a VM. Gotta study more about case sensitivity in hosts and guests...